# Coresphere console : ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Tags: php, symfony

I get this error any time I try to run the command

```
assetic:dump --env PROD
```

in the `coresphereConsoleBundle` on my local project :

```
/web/app_dev.php/_console
```

According to several posts, the solution is to turn off PHP's **session.auto_start**. But this is already set to false. Below is my verbose error message:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcu9S.png)